# How to get process not responding on remote server with Powershell

Tags: powershell, process

I don't understand, responding is empty on remote serveur.

```
Get-Process explorer -ComputerName vcass1 | select name,id,responding

Name                                               Id Responding
----                                               -- ----------
explorer                                         1204
explorer                                         3020
```

but responding i real empty :

```
Get-Process explorer -ComputerName vcass1 | Where-Object {$_.Responding -eq $true}
>> No result

Get-Process explorer -ComputerName vcass1 | Where-Object {$_.Responding -eq $false}
>> No result
```

when i try with : **-ComputerName localhost** i have the same problem, but without **-ComputerName** i have value **$True** for each process !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [help on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.responding.aspx) you should get a `NotSupportedException` error indictaing that:

> You are attempting to access the Responding property for a process
>   that is running on a remote computer. This property is available only
>   for processes that are running on the local computer.

Answer (score 0):

If the remote server is on Windows 2012 you can read the **Responding** status remotely.